# Sub query using Oracle 8i

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

We have a SQL script that creates a CSV using the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT auf_kopf.auf_nr, TO_CHAR(auf_kopf.erfass_dat,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(auf_kopf.liefer_dat,'DD/MM/YYYY'), v_ord_custname.cust_name, auf_pos.auf_pos, v_auf_stat_0.anz, v_reason_code_1.reason_code, v_reason_code_1.reason_desc, v_auf_pos_vmat.glas1, auf_pos.glas2, auf_kopf.auf_off, auf_pos.ver_art
FROM auf_kopf, auf_pos, v_auf_pos_vmat, v_auf_stat_0, v_ord_custname, v_reason_code_1, glas_daten_basis
WHERE auf_kopf.erfass_dat >sysdate-7
AND auf_kopf.kopf_reason IS NOT NULL
AND (auf_kopf.auf_nr=auf_pos.auf_nr(+))
AND (auf_pos.auf_nr=v_auf_pos_vmat.auf_nr(+))
AND (auf_pos.auf_pos=v_auf_pos_vmat.auf_pos(+))
AND (auf_pos.variante=v_auf_pos_vmat.variante(+))
AND (auf_pos.auf_nr=v_auf_stat_0.auf_nr)
AND (auf_pos.auf_pos=v_auf_stat_0.auf_pos)
AND (auf_pos.variante=v_auf_stat_0.variante)
AND (auf_kopf.auf_nr=v_ord_custname.order_no)
AND (auf_kopf.auf_nr=v_reason_code_1.order_no(+));
```

There is a table called `glas_daten_basis` that contains descriptions for the codes shown from `v_auf_pos_vmat.glas1` and `auf_pos.glas2`. How do we show the description also as I think a sub query is required but I couldn't get it to work.

We need `glas_daten_basis.gl_bez` (description) for `v_auf_pos_vmat.glas1` and `auf_pos.glas2`. The codes can be matched using `glas_daten_basis.idnr` and `v_auf_pos_vmat.glas1`.

Comment: Looks like ANSI-89 standard, should probably be changed to ANSI-92 standard with INNER JOINs. Very old and deprecated code...

Comment: @twoleggedhorse - Oracle didn't add support for ANSI joins until 9i; if the OP is really using 8i then they aren't an option. Though that might be the least of their problems...

Comment: @AlexPoole So what is the solution? Please can you post an example?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can follow this, I think you just need to join to `glas_daten_basis` twice:

```
SELECT DISTINCT auf_kopf.auf_nr, TO_CHAR(auf_kopf.erfass_dat,'DD/MM/YYYY'), 
  TO_CHAR(auf_kopf.liefer_dat,'DD/MM/YYYY'), v_ord_custname.cust_name, 
  auf_pos.auf_pos, v_auf_stat_0.anz, v_reason_code_1.reason_code,
  v_reason_code_1.reason_desc,
  v_auf_pos_vmat.glas1 ||' '|| gd_basis1.gl_bez as glas1,
  auf_pos.glas2 ||' '|| gd_basis2.gl_bez as glas2,
  auf_kopf.auf_off, auf_pos.ver_art
FROM auf_kopf, auf_pos, v_auf_pos_vmat, v_auf_stat_0, v_ord_custname,
  v_reason_code_1, glas_daten_basis gd_basis1, glas_daten_basis gd_basis2
WHERE auf_kopf.erfass_dat >sysdate-7
AND auf_kopf.kopf_reason IS NOT NULL
AND (auf_kopf.auf_nr=auf_pos.auf_nr(+))
AND (auf_pos.auf_nr=v_auf_pos_vmat.auf_nr(+))
AND (auf_pos.auf_pos=v_auf_pos_vmat.auf_pos(+))
AND (auf_pos.variante=v_auf_pos_vmat.variante(+))
AND (auf_pos.auf_nr=v_auf_stat_0.auf_nr)
AND (auf_pos.auf_pos=v_auf_stat_0.auf_pos)
AND (auf_pos.variante=v_auf_stat_0.variante)
AND (auf_kopf.auf_nr=v_ord_custname.order_no)
AND (auf_kopf.auf_nr=v_reason_code_1.order_no(+))
AND (v_auf_pos_vmat.glas1 = gd_basis1.idnr(+))
AND (auf_pos.glas2 = gd_basis2.idnr(+));
```

I've aliased the two references to that table so you can distinguish between them. One instance of the table is outer joined to `v_auf_pos_vmat`, the other to `auf_pos`. It's been a while since I've used the old `(+)` notation, but I think I've got them in the right place for what you're doing...

Incidentally, the brackets around all the conditions are unnecessary though, since there is no ambiguity to resolve.

Comment: This error message is received `AND (v_auf_pos.glas2 = gd_basis_2.idnr(+))
                                  *
ERROR at line 20:
ORA-00904: invalid column name`. Are you able to help?

Comment: @user2656114 - I was inconsistent with my alias names, and had a stray `v_`. That should have complained about the table names, though, not the column names.

Comment: @user2656114 - sure; you could concatenate the values at the point you create the CSV, but for now I've shown how to do that in the query. The two values have `||' '||` between them, which puts a space between them in the final value. And I've aliased those so they can be referred to later.

Comment: That's great, working now, I didn't notice that mistake sorry. I did a search online but couldn't find anything, do you know if it's possible that `v_auf_pos_vmat.glas1` and `gd_basis1.gl_bez` get combined in the CSV? So for e.g. ,'$code $description',?